# Find text and format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have recorded a macro in Word 2007 that finds a word, moves the cursor two lines up, inserts three '***', then highlights the line. It works on the first instance of the found word. I am struggling to get it to repeat throughout the document with all instances of the word I want it to find.

This is the output from my recorded macro. I need the actions to be repeated for each instance of "B,".

```
 Sub HighlightNewItems()
'
' HighlightNewItems Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "B,"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeText Text:="***"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following construct within your `With.Selection.Find`

```
Do While .Execute
  '(logic that you want to apply after finding string)
Loop
```

In your case, your code would look like

```
Sub HighlightNewItems()
'
' HighlightNewItems Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "B,"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

      Do While .Execute
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        Selection.TypeText Text:="***"
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      Loop 

    End With

End Sub
```